# Make a 'Choice' field with Allow 'Fill-in' choices remember the choice

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, custom-list

Im using the 'Choice' type for one of my lists, and would like the users to be able to add their own choices.

I then chose True in "Allow 'Fill-in' choices".
This works like a charm, but my users complain that they have to enter their same choices over and over again.

Is it possible to make the list "remember" all the custom choices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is available OOB but if your are open to some custom coding here are your choices:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/6f957873-9780-48ed-b683-5ab7de05b375/allow-fillin-for-choice-column-adding-the-filledin-field-to-the-current-choice-list?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: Thank you, but the examples as kind of old. I guess there are other ways to do it in SP2013?